# Updating state twice when the button is clicked, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, updating, eventhandler

I want to create simple 2048 game application. My initial board is composed of 16 array elements.
The generate() function generates a value of '2' in a random empty element

It works just fine and creates one random '2' for me, but the problem starts when I want to call it twice in a handler like this:

```
  const handleNewGame = () => {
      generate()
      generate()
  }
```

I've read about prevState but have no idea how to implement it in this batch of code to work properly.

Here is my game component:

```
const width = 4;

const Game = () => {
  const [Board, setBoard] = useState([]);

  const createBoard = () => {
    let initialBoard = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
      initialBoard.push("");
    }
    return initialBoard;
  };

  const generate = () => {
    let board = [...Board];
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Board.length);
    console.log(randomNumber);
    if (board[randomNumber] === "") {
      board[randomNumber] = 2;
      setBoard(board);
    } else generate()
  };

  const handleNewGame = () => {
      generate()
      generate()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setBoard(createBoard);
    console.log(`Board Created!`);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="game-container">
      <button onClick={handleNewGame}>NewGame</button>
      <div className="game">
        {Board.map((value, index) => (
          <div className="tile" key={index}>
            {value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

I'll be glad for the answer.

Comment: You have to provide a reproducable example, provide more code, so what we can copy and run

Comment: Ok, posted the whole component

Comment: I din't understand your question. I will tell you what I have understood. Please correct me If I am wrong => You want 2 different numbers to be generated and both should be stored in the `Board` array. But only one is stored in that array right ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState(), named setBoard() in your code is asynchronous, whatch this great video on the Event Loop for you to understand more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ.

See if this will suit your needs:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const width = 4;

const Game = () => {
    const [Board, setBoard] = useState([]);

    const createBoard = () => {
        let initialBoard = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
            initialBoard.push('');
        }
        return initialBoard;
    };

    const randomBoardPosition = () => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Board.length);
    };

    const generate = () => {
        let board = createBoard();
        let randomNumber = randomBoardPosition();
        let positionsFilled = 0;

        while (positionsFilled < 2) {
            if (board[randomNumber] === '') {
                board[randomNumber] = 2;
                positionsFilled++;
            } else {
                randomNumber = randomBoardPosition();
            }
        }
        setBoard(board);
    };

    const handleNewGame = () => {
        generate();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setBoard(createBoard);
        console.log(`Board Created!`);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="game-container">
            <button onClick={handleNewGame}>NewGame</button>
            <div className="game">
                {Board.map((value, index) => (
                    <div className="tile" key={index}>
                        {value}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Game;
```

Comment: No, generating one random number works just fine. I want to generate it twice when I click the "New Game" button. This take doesn't work:
~~~
const handleNewGame = () => {
      generate()
      generate()
  }
~~~

Comment: I have updated the main post, hope it is more readable now.

Comment: I tested your code, and every time i clicked in the New Game, a number 2 appeared in a random position, adding to the current board, until all positions were filled with number 2. This is really the intented bahaviour? Why do you need to generate 2 times? whats the expected result?

Comment: It has to generate two '2' by clicking only once.

Comment: I edited my answer, see if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just us function instead of value

```
const generate = () => {
  setBoard(Board => {
    let board = [...Board];
    while (true) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Board.length);
      console.log(randomNumber);
      if (board[randomNumber] === "") {
        board[randomNumber] = 2;
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not used to that setState syntax, I only use arrow functions. Is there a way to do this with setBoard function?